# XPath Assistance Combining Two XPath to Get Exact Element

Tags: xpath

I have a bunch of div elements and I am trying to find a single one called with the text 'Audit Follow-up'

`<div _ngcontent-qwq-c149="" class="section-text font-bold ng-tns-c149-164"> Audit Follow-up </div>`

I have tried doing this: `//div[contains(@class, 'section-text font-bold')]` This gives me four elements to choose from.

Doing this `//div[contains(string(), 'Audit Follow-up')]` gives me seven results.

I have also tried doing this: `//div[contains(., 'Audit Follow-up')]` which also gives me 7 results.

Is there a way to combine the two XPaths so I can get just the one called `Audit Follow-up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to select exact `div` node:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'section-text font-bold') and normalize-space()='Audit Follow-up']
```

If text is unique you can select by text only

```
//div[normalize-space(text())='Audit Follow-up']
```

Comment: @DarthOpto the initial version of second one been updated. Try it once again - it should work as well